# Need help to compute the limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So I have the following exercise:

[exercise photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oGWu.png)

I have determined that the series is convergent. But I do not know how to compute the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n}$ =$\frac{1}{1-x}$ . valid for -1< x<1 . One can differentiate the series term by term at x =$\frac{1}{2}$ that the sum of this series that you are asking about is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ which at x=$\frac{1}{2}$ is 4

Answer (score 0):

The series is convergent by ratio test. For any convergent series $\sum a_n$ of positive terms $\lim \sum_n ^{2n} a_k =0$. In fact $\lim \sum_n ^{\infty} a_k =0$.

Comment: May I ask, is it because since the series is convergent, then  $\lim a_n = 0$, and it goes the same for $\lim a_{n+1}$, $\lim a_{n+2}$, ... ? Asking because I would like to know to also prove it in case I will have something similar on my exam.

Comment: No, it is not because $a_n \to 0$. Let $s_n$ be the n-th partial sum. Then $s_n \to s$ say. Now $\sum_n ^{2n} a_n =s_{2n} -s_n \to s-s=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly for $k=n,\dotsc, 2n$, $n\leq k \leq 2n$, so
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{2^{k-1}}
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{2n}{2^{k-1}}$$
and also note that
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}
= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \frac{1-(1/ 2)^{n+1}}{1- (1/ 2)}
= \frac{4}{2^n} (1- (1/ 2)^{n+1})$$
then
$$\underbrace{\frac{4 n}{2^n}}_{\to 0} \cdot \underbrace{(1-(1/ 2)^{n+1})}_{\to 1} = \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{2^{k-1}}
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{2n}{2^{k-1}}
= \underbrace{\frac{8 n}{2^n}}_{\to 0} \underbrace{(1-(1/ 2)^{n+1})}_{\to 1}$$

So the limit is zero by the squeeze theorem.